# unityのプロジェクトが2度と開けなくなる

Tags: unity3d

Windows10Pro64bitにunityhubをインストールし、適当なバージョンのunityをインストールしました
ライセンスはpersonalです
プロジェクトを作成、保存、unityを終了した後、再度プロジェクトを開こうとしても、添付のエラーメッセージが一瞬表示されるのみで、unityhubのプロジェクト一覧画面に戻ってしまいます

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

unityは最新のバージョン以外にもいくつか試しましたが、いずれも同じ結果でした

ネットで検索し対応してみましたがだめでした
・パスに全角文字を含めないこと
ユーザーは全角でしたが、インストールパス・プロジェクトパスは半角であることを確認しました
・プロジェクトを起動する時にネットワークを無効にしておく
サーバが見つからないというエラーになりました
・マルウェア対策アプリを止めること
止めましたが変わりありませんでした

ユーザー名が全角でしたので、新たにwindowsのローカルユーザーを作成し、unityhubのインストールから試してみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした
対応方法ありましたら、教えていただけると助かります

Comment: exploerでシーンを直接開くとUnityが起動しプロジェクトとして開くことが出来ました  ただ正常に動くか確認出来ていないので、もう少し試します

Comment: 開けたのですがビルドするとAndoridのところでエラーになりました。別内容なので改めて質問出してみます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました
私のPCにはネットワークアダプタがオンボード×1、WiFi×1がついています
WiFiは使用しないので、Windowsのネットワーク接続を無効にしていました

それ(WiFi)を有効にします
有線はそのまま使用します
するとUnityのライセンス認証がエラーになるので、再度手動認証します
そうすると、プロジェクトが開けるようになりました

実はオンボードは2ついているのですが、有効にするとWindowsがハングアップするのでUEFIで無効にしています
プロジェクトが開けるようになっても、WiFiを無効にするとまた開けなくなりました
なのでWiFiもUEFIで無効にしてもよいかもしれませんが、試していません
Unityのライセンス認証はネットワークアダプタが関係しているということが分かったので、色々ためした結果です